# Hide hours and mins if they are zero in the function provided

Tags: php, date, string, if-statement

The function below outputs hours:0 whether the time is <1 hour or mins:0 when mins<1.

How can I show only the variables that are not zero?

Thank you.

```
function time_difference($endtime){

    $hours =date("G",$endtime);
    $mins =date("i",$endtime);
    $secs =date("s",$endtime);
    $diff="'hours': ".$hours.",'mins': ".$mins.",'sec': ".$secs;
    return $diff;
}   

$end_time =strtotime("+7 hours") - strtotime($entry->pubDate);
$difference = time_difference($end_time);
echo $difference;
```

Comment: Variables that are zero are not empty.  They have a value; that value is zero.

Comment: @Paul actually a variable that has the value `0` is considered `empty` in php :).

Comment: @bazmegakapa in all versions?

Comment: Since the beginning of PHP time :). See [empty() in Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues).

Comment: This is a good knowledge. Is it the same for other languages ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible approach:

```
function time_difference($endtime){
    $times=array(
        'hours' => date("G",$endtime),
        'mins' => date("i",$endtime),
        'secs' => date("s",$endtime),
    );

    //added a "just a moment ago" feature for you
    if (intval($times['hours'], 10) == 0 
           && intval($times['mins'], 10) == 0) {
        return "just a moment ago";
    } 

    $diff='';
    foreach ($times as $k=>$v) {
        $diff.=empty($diff) ? '' : ',';
        $diff.=intval($v, 10) == 0 ? '' : "'$k':$v";
    }

    return $diff;
}
```

Comment: Having a foreach loop is faster than arrays like the solution above ?

Comment: @Punkis Taking the differences between the two codes, it's hard to tell which one is faster and it does not really matter at this level (that would be micro-optimization). Readability matters more.

Comment: @Punkis Added a "just a moment ago" for you.

Comment: Tank you for the info. I have tested it and one of my posts appeared as 'mins':00,'secs':46 ( it should be "just a moment". The following post is shown as 'mins':03,'secs':46 if it helps.

Comment: @Punkis Oh yes, I forgot about the fact that `date` will add padding zeros, so `empty` will not interpret it correctly. Let me just correct this quickly.

Comment: Thank for the quick reply. Here is what i got. Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context. I have updated my question with the last part of the code... hope it helps.

Comment: @Punkis Dammit, in the end I will get this right (drunken like hell) :). Now it should be alright. `empty` cannot be used on function return values.

Comment: @bazmegapa, how can I change the output to something like 2 hours and 30 minutes? I am not using secs anymore. Also how can I change hours to my language? (greek)

Answer (score 2):

Use the ? operator.

```
$diff=($hours > 0) ? "'hours': ".$hours : "";
$diff=$diff.($minutes > 0) ? etc...
```

Comment: My mistake. How can I show a "just a moment ago" if the time passed is <1 minute ?

Comment: in the end do:
if($hours < 1 && $minutes < 1 && $seconds < 1) $diff = "Just a moment ago";

Comment: You mean like this? I dont get the expected results. `$diff=($hours > 0) ? "'hours': ".$hours : "";
$diff=$diff.($mins > 0) ? "'mins': ".$mins : "";
$diff=$diff.($secs > 0) ? "'secs': ".$secs : "";
if($hours < 1 && $minutes < 1 && $seconds < 1) $diff = "Just a moment ago";`

Comment: oh sorry remove the "&& $seconds < 1" part

Answer (score 1):

For larger time ranges, you'd better use maths instead of using `date()`:

```
function time_difference($endtime){
    // hours can get over 23 now, $endtime is in seconds
    $hours = floor($endtime / 3600);
    // modulo (%) already rounds down, not need to use floor()
    $mins = $endtime / 60 % 60;
    // the remainder of $endtime / 60 are seconds in a minute
    $secs = $endtime % 60;
    // this array holds the hour, minute and seconds if greater than 0
    $diff = array();
    if ($hours) $diff[] = "'hours': $hours";
    if ($mins) $diff[] = "'mins': $mins";
    if ($secs) $diff[] = "'sec': $secs";
    // join the values with a comma
    $diff = implode(',', $diff);
    if (!$diff) { // hours, mins and secs are zero
        $diff = "just a moment ago";
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

The below function would only return hours in the range 0 - 23. If the time exceeds a day, hours become zero:

```
function time_difference($endtime){

    $hours = (int)date("G",$endtime);
    $mins = (int)date("i",$endtime);
    $secs = (int)date("s",$endtime);
    // this array holds the hour, minute and seconds if greater than 0
    $diff = array();
    if ($hours) $diff[] = "'hours': $hours";
    if ($mins) $diff[] = "'mins': $mins";
    if ($secs) $diff[] = "'sec': $secs";
    // join the values with a comma
    $diff = implode(',', $diff);
    if (!$diff) { // hours, mins and secs are zero
        $diff = "just a moment ago";
    }
    return $diff;
}
```

`(int)` is needed to turn the string returned by `date()` into a string. `"01"` becomes 1 and `"00"` becomes "0" using this.

Comment: Hi Lekensteyn, how can I show a "just a moment ago" when hours and mins are empty ?

Comment: @mtopia: If you're going to need days, you probably do not want to truncate the time. I've added new code to the answer. If you want to display date, replace `$hours = floor($endtime / 3600);` by `$days = floor($endtime / 3600 / 24);$hours = $endtime / 3600 / 24 % 24;` and add a `if ($days) $diff[] = "'days': $days";` before `if ($hours)`